# Can any one help me in mocking a static method which returns an object, and this static method is present in a final class

Tags: junit, powermock

I need help for below thing,

I have to write a Junit using PowerMock/Mockito for a method which makes a call to a static method of a final class present in an external jar.

The method for which i need to write the JUnit test is:

```
public class SomeClass {
    private PrivateKey privateKeyFromPkcs8(String privateKeyPem) throws IOException {
        Reader reader = new StringReader(privateKeyPem);
        Section section = PemReader.readFirstSectionAndClose(reader, "PRIVATE KEY");
        if (section == null) {
            throw new IOException("Invalid PKCS8 data.");
        }
        byte[] bytes = section.getBase64DecodedBytes();
        PKCS8EncodedKeySpec keySpec = new PKCS8EncodedKeySpec(bytes);
        try {
            KeyFactory keyFactory = SecurityUtils.getRsaKeyFactory();
            PrivateKey privateKey = keyFactory.generatePrivate(keySpec);
            return privateKey;
        } catch (NoSuchAlgorithmException exception) {
        } catch (InvalidKeySpecException exception) {
        }
        throw new IOException("Unexpected exception reading PKCS data");
    }
}
```

In the above code `PemReader` is a final class and `readFirstSectionAndClose(reader, "PRIVATE KEY")` is a static method in `PemReader`.

I have tried writing the test shown below but `Section object(section)` is showing as null while debugging. Perhaps the actual code (`PemReader.readFirstSectionAndClose(reader, "PRIVATE KEY")`) is getting called instead of the mock.

```
@RunWith(PowerMockRunner.class)
@PrepareForTest({SomeClass.class,PemReader.class})
public class SomeClassTest {
    @InjectMocks
    SomeClass mockSomeClass;

    @Mock
    private Reader mockReader;

    @Mock
    private Section mockSection;

    @Test
    public void testPrivateKeyFromPkcs8() throws Exception {   
        PowerMockito.mockStatic(PemReader.class);
        Mockito.when(PemReader.readFirstSectionAndClose(mockReader, "PRIVATE KEY")).thenReturn(mockSection);

        assertNotNull(mockSomeClass.privateKeyFromPkcs8(dummyPrivateKey));
    } 

 }
```

Please help me in writing a Junit using powermockito/mockito

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You have to *prepare* the final, static class.

Here's an example using the PowerMock annotations for JUnit:

```
@RunWith(PowerMockRunner.class)
@PrepareForTest({PemReader.class})
public class PemReaderTest {

    @Mock
    private Reader mockReader;

    @Mock
    private Section mockSection;

    @Test
    public void testMockingStatic() {
        PowerMockito.mockStatic(PemReader.class);

        Mockito.when(PemReader.readFirstSectionAndClose(mockReader, "PRIVATE KEY")).thenReturn(mockSection);

        Assert.assertEquals(mockSection, PemReader.readFirstSectionAndClose(mockReader, "PRIVATE KEY"));
    }
}
```

For completeness, here's the definition of `PemReader`:

```
public final class PemReader {

    public static Section readFirstSectionAndClose(Reader reader, String key) {
        return null;
    }
}
```

The above test passes with the following versions:

- JUnit: `4.12`
- Mockito: `2.7.19`
- PowerMock: `1.7.0`

**Update 1**: based on your updated question. Your test case will pass (or at least the invocation on `PemReader.readFirstSectionAndClose` will return something) if you just make this change:

```
Mockito.when(PemReader.readFirstSectionAndClose(
    Mockito.any(Reader.class), 
    Mockito.eq("PRIVATE KEY"))
).thenReturn(mockSection);
```

The version of this instruction in your current test case relies on equality matching between the `StringReader` which your code passes into `readFirstSectionAndClose` and the mocked `Reader` which your test case supplies. These are not 'equal' hence the mocked invocation's expectations are not met and your `mockSection` is not returned.

A few, unrelated, notes:

- There is no need to include `SomeClass.class` in `@PrepareForTest`, you only need to include the classes which you want to mock in that annotation, since `SomeClass` is the class you are trying to test there is no mocking required for that class.
- Using `@InjectMocks` to instance `SomeClass` is a bit odd, since `SomeClass` has no (mockito provided) mocks to inject into it :) you can replace this declaration with `SomeClass someClass = new SomeClass();`
- In the code you supplied `SomeClass.privateKeyFromPkcs8` has private scope so it cannot be tested (or called in any way) from `SomeClassTest`.

Comment: Let me explain the real problem. i have a class say Class x , in which i have a method      private PrivateKey privateKeyFromPkcs8(String privateKeyPem)   below is the code of the method

Comment: private PrivateKey privateKeyFromPkcs8(String privateKeyPem) throws IOException {
Reader reader = new StringReader(privateKeyPem);
Section section = PemReader.readFirstSectionAndClose(reader, "PRIVATE KEY");
if (section == null) {
throw new IOException("Invalid PKCS8 data.");
}
byte[] bytes = section.getBase64DecodedBytes();
PKCS8EncodedKeySpec keySpec = new PKCS8EncodedKeySpec(bytes);
try {
KeyFactory keyFactory = SecurityUtils.getRsaKeyFactory();
PrivateKey privateKey = keyFactory.generatePrivate(keySpec);
return privateKey;
} catch (NoSuchAlgorithmException exception) {

Comment: } catch (InvalidKeySpecException exception) {
}
throw new IOException("Unexpected exception reading PKCS data");
}

Comment: And i want to do a test this method using Junit. Please help how to write.

Comment: @gopinaik sounds like that might require a separate question or at the very least update this question to include those details and a statement of what you want this test to do. It is very difficult to understand code posted in comments especially when that code is split across two comments :)

Comment: Hi Glitch, i have update my Question . Can you please help me now.

Comment: @gopinaik I took your updated question, reproduced the 'null repsonse' issue locally and then fixed it, the updated answer includes the fix.

Comment: its working now. The section object is not null now. Thank you :)